# How do I pause a download in the Launchpad in OS X Lion?

Tags: data-transfer, launchpad

I started downloading XCode on my 10 mbit/s but it is 4 GB and I want to pause it for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Mission Control and just click on the Downloading Xcode icon. This will pause it. Clicking again will resume.

Answer (score 3):

If you're downloading via the App Store, if you click on the Purchased icon at the top of the App Store window, I *think* that there's the option to Pause an active download. I seem to remember seeing it while I downloaded Lion earlier today.